# Как сделать проверку тригера на компонент BP

Tags: unreal-engine-4

Только начал работать с *UE4* и столкнулся с такой проблемой:
У меня есть `Component` **W** и `Box Collision` **Box_centr**. Я пытаюсь сделать что когда **Box_centr** соприкасается с **W** должно происходить действие к примеру вывод сообщение.

Что я делаю, Создаю функцию и пытаюсь в нее передать колизию , Типы данных одинаковые на пишет ошибку что нет[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вроде в обоих местах `Object Reference`

Я знаю что можно сделать так.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в дальнейшем я не смогу делать то что мне нужно если сделаю данный вариант.

Если описать полностью что у меня делается. у меня создается Коробка и вокруг нее спавнится 4  триггера в направлениях `+-X` и `+- Y` , я пытаюсь сделать что бы если следующий спавн попадает в триггера  он не спавнил ничего

Answer (score 1):

**OtherActor** указывает на актор, который попал в коллизию, а не на его компонент.
Попробуйте сделать каст на ваш класс TBPPerentsTest. Если нужен компонент, возьмите с **OtherComp**